# How do I parse text into a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have a dhcp lease file with the following example entries:

> lease 172.16.20.11 {
>    starts 4 2014/10/09 18:33:57;
>    ends 4 2014/10/09 18:43:57;
>    cltt 4 2014/10/09 18:33:57;
>    binding state active;
>    next binding state free;
>    rewind binding state free;
>    hardware ethernet XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;
>    client-hostname "phone";
>   }

I am trying to find a way to convert the information into JSON so I can use in Dojo.

I would like the output to be like

```
{"leases": ["address":"172.16.20.11", "starts":"2014/10/09 18:33:57", "ends":"2014/10/09 18:43:57","
client-hostname":"phone"]}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Tim T

Comment: Not easily...Parse each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'lease 172.16.20.11 { starts 4 2014/10/09 18:33:57; ends 4 2014/10/09 18:43:57; cltt 4 2014/10/09 18:33:57; binding state active; next binding state free; rewind binding state free; hardware ethernet XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX; client-hostname "phone"; }';

var res = str.split(/[\s;]+/); // regex match spaces and semicolons

// Create your leases array with a lease object from the parsed string
var leases = {leases:[{
address: res[1],
starts: res[5] + " " + res[6],
ends: res[9] + res[10],
client_hostname: res[30].split('"')[1]
}]};

var json = JSON.stringify(leases); //convert the array of leases to json string
```

[EDIT] client-hostname must be client_hostname because of variable name restrictions

[EDIT] changed leases to be an object with an array property to more closely match your desired output

[EDIT] parsed phone from "phone" for client_hostname

Comment: McCallbear, I have a new issue. It works great with one entry, but how do I iterate through a file with multiple dhcp addresses?